# Как реализовать вывод ошибки при делении на 0?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно, чтобы в поле ввода при делении на 0 отображалась ошибка, вроде "на 0 делить нельзя" и т.п.

```js
    var Fcalc = document.calc;
    var Currents = 0;
    var FlagNewNum = false;
    var PendingOp = "";


     // обработчик нажатия 
     // цифровой кнопки
    function NumPressed(Num) {
      if (FlagNewNum) {
        Fcalc.ReadOut.value = Num;
        FlagNewNum = false;
      } else {
        if (Fcalc.ReadOut.value == "0")
          Fcalc.ReadOut.value = Num;
        else
          Fcalc.ReadOut.value += Num;
      }
    }

     // обработчик нажатия
     // кнопки действия
    function Operation(Op) {
      var Readout = Fcalc.ReadOut.value;
      if (FlagNewNum && PendingOp != "=") {
        Fcalc.ReadOut.value = Currents;
      } else {
        FlagNewNum = true;
        if ('+' == PendingOp)
          Currents += parseFloat(Readout);
        else if ('-' == PendingOp)
          Currents -= parseFloat(Readout);
        else if ('/' == PendingOp)
          Currents /= parseFloat(Readout);
        else if ('*' == PendingOp)
          Currents *= parseFloat(Readout);
        else
          Currents = parseFloat(Readout);
        Fcalc.ReadOut.value = Currents;
        PendingOp = Op;
      }
    }

     // добавление десятичной точки с числу
    function Decimal() {
      var curReadOut = Fcalc.ReadOut.value;
      if (FlagNewNum) {
        curReadOut = "0.";
        FlagNewNum = false;
      } else {
        if (curReadOut.indexOf(".") == -1)
          curReadOut += ".";
      }
      Fcalc.ReadOut.value = curReadOut;
    }

     // Очистка текущего результата
    function ClearEntry() {
      Fcalc.ReadOut.value = "0";
      FlagNewNum = true;
    }

     // Полная очистка всех результатов
    function Clear() {
      Currents = 0;
      PendingOp = "";
      ClearEntry();

    }


     // меняем знак текущего результата
    function Neg() {
      Fcalc.ReadOut.value =
        parseFloat(Fcalc.ReadOut.value) * -1;
    }

     // вычисляем значение процентов
    function Percent() {
      Fcalc.ReadOut.value =
        (parseFloat(Fcalc.ReadOut.value) / 100) *
        parseFloat(Currents);
    }
```

```css
.tblCalc {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}
.tblCalc input {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 4px;
}
#btnWide {
  width: 80px;
}
#editWide {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<form name="calc" action="">
  <table class="tblCalc" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=5 align=middle>
        <input id="editWide" name="ReadOut" type="Text" size=28 value="0" width="250px">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnClear" type="Button" value="C" onclick="Clear()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnClearEntry" type="Button" value="CE" onclick="ClearEntry()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="btnSeven" type="Button" value="7" onclick="NumPressed(7)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnEight" type="Button" value="8" onclick="NumPressed(8)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnNine" type="Button" value="9" onclick="NumPressed(9)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnPlus" type="Button" value="+" onclick="Operation('+')" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnMultiply" type="Button" value="*" onclick="Operation('*')" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="btnFour" type="Button" value="4" onclick="NumPressed(4)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnFive" type="Button" value="5" onclick="NumPressed(5)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnSix" type="Button" value="6" onclick="NumPressed(6)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnMinus" type="Button" value="-" onclick="Operation('-')" />
      </td>
      <td align=middle>
        <input name="btnDivide" type="Button" value=" / " onclick="Operation('/')" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="btnOne" type="Button" value="1" onclick="NumPressed(1)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnTwo" type="Button" value="2" onclick="NumPressed(2)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnThree" type="Button" value="3" onclick="NumPressed(3)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnPercent" type="Button" value="%" onclick="Percent()" />
      </td>
      <td align=middle>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="btnZero" type="Button" value="0" onclick="NumPressed(0)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnDecimal" type="Button" value="." onclick="Decimal()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="btnNeg" type="button" value="+/-" onclick="Neg()" />
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input id="btnWide" name="btnEquals" type="Button" value="=" onclick="Operation('=')">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: А что бы просто не проверить делитель в соотв. блоке кода? ну который `else if ( '/' == PendingOp )`

Comment: выше правильные мысли) при делении на 0 результат вычисления - infinity (бесконечность), добавить условие, если результат == бесконечности - очищаем переменные + алерт какой-то, что на 0 делить нельзя

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы после алерта c сообщением не появлялось "infinity" в поле ответа ?